# Narrow return type based on input using generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to narrow the return type of a function based on the specific shape of the input, using generics. Is this even possible in TypeScript? I have the following MRE that demonstrates the issue:

```
type ValidInput = {
   filename: string;
   sender: number;
};

type ValidInput2 = {
   person: string;
   sender: string;
};

type InferSenderType<T extends { sender: any }> = T extends { sender: infer K }
  ? K
  : unknown;

type Api<I extends { sender: any }> = (input: I) => InferSenderType<I>;

declare const loadFile: Api<ValidInput | ValidInput2>;

const a = loadFile({ filename: "q", sender: 3 }); 

typeof a // string | number 

// How do I get it to narrow the return type (in this case 'number') based on the input?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
type ValidInput = {
   filename: string;
   sender: number;
};

type ValidInput2 = {
   person: string;
   sender: string;
};

type Api = <I extends { sender: any }>(input: I) => I['sender']

declare const loadFile: Api;

const a = loadFile({ filename: "q", sender: 3 }); 

typeof a // only number
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMCSA7MBXYUC8UA3gFBTkBmSCEGcAthAFxQDOwATkhgOYDcZcq1ooIHFhmz0ARmIEBfASVCRYiVJhzAATAWKCokDqwD2GFuy68B5NiLEXO3fiUUll4aAEEwSPQB40KAgAD2ARVmI7DFFxKDgMECh5AD4ACm4tFjQASgIUqDQAbQByYRixEoBdd1EAYwQ4Dmg6s3YoBBM4FAAxamYoHyQlVox2uD1O7r6aNKIoKho6RhYAIgBHVYAaaNiWAGZknL4odxUIEwp4qAB6G7YnXigAHyhJGTFToA)